# How do I access a dynamic element with selenium that returns None

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find an attribute 'src' via selenium to get an image but instead of returning the element. it returns a None type. I think its doing it because it is JavaScript. I want to know is there a way to still get the attribute instead of a None type? please help

script

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from webdriver_manager.opera import OperaDriverManager
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install())

video_list = []

url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@nkosazana_daughter"


driver.get(url)

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    popup = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="tiktok-verify-ele"]/div')

    if popup is False:
        driver.quit()
    elif popup is not None:
        popup_pic = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="captcha-verify-image"]')
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    pic = popup_pic.get_attribute('src')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic, 'pic.png')
    img = Image.open('pic.png')
    print(img.getpixel(xy=(0,5)))
    print(img.getbbox())
    print(img.getbands())
    print(img.getdata(0))

    
    pic2 = popup.get_attribute('src')
    print(pic2)
```

output

```
(88, 102, 49)
(0, 0, 552, 344)
('R', 'G', 'B')
<ImagingCore object at 0x0000025C45276AF0>
None
```

Comment: don't think it's valid to have a space in an attribute name.  Are you sure there is an attribute of "alt src"?  The "alt" tag is usually for text to display when the client doesn't support graphics.... (or for text displayed upon hover).

Comment: <img class="captcha_verify_img_slide react-draggable sc-VigVT ggNWOG" alt="" src="https://p16-captcha-va.ibyteimg.com/tos-maliva-i-71rtze2081-us/91ad220671544f109570711d5e99cb48~tplv-71rtze2081-1.png" style="left: 0px; top: 0.973188em; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">. you are right. the way it is in the inspect panel makes it seem like its one word but its not.

Answer (score 0):

[**alt**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) and [**src**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) are two different HTML attributes.

To print the value of the *`src`* attribute you can use the following line of code:

```
print(popup.get_attribute('src'))
```

Comment: you rare right and I edited it out of my code but I still get that None type for that attribute

Comment: @HoustonMhlongo Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: even after removing the 'alt' and running the code again. The attribute still returns the None type instead of data. So the question has changed.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Could you help with this question by chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571002/python-selenium-how-to-retrieve-base64-images-after-clicking-a-button/73633379?noredirect=1#comment130036478_73633379